# OS X menubar extras + Apple HIG + UX pattern in conflict - when quit isn't quit

Tags: objective-c, macos, user-experience, menubar

A quick search of [Apple's Human Interface Guidelines and Developer Library yields an unequivocal guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/MenuBarMenus.html):

> Users, and not apps, place menu bar extras in the menu bar.

Anecdotal data backs that up: submitting an app where - upon quit of a dock process/main view, the extra is left running - yields a tidy rejection.

Now - I'm a  User experience designer (UXD) who typically plays, I mean, works in the mobile and web space. So please pardon my lack of Obj C chops, thanks.

I understand well the guideline and behavior/pattern: apps like Skitch, Wunderlist, Evernote, et al however very clearly leave the extra (often termed HelperApp) running in the menu bar on quit of main app. They all, ***do*** offer explicit user toggle of this w/i preferences.

There's no additional Human Interface Guidelines w/ specifics around handling this requirement for user control. Must this be included in onboarding? Dialog at 1st quit? Again: I can speak to best behavior UX wise, but my (very senior) dev wants the mandate - how are **others** not getting rejected?

Focus: what means of user control is/are mandated to avoid rejection?
Known/given: include in preferences
Other: ???

After hours of searching online and Apple Dev guidelines, I humbly bring this question here. There simply isn't time to play a carnival game of requirements: guess, get rejected, repeat. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a button somewhere in your user interface that adds the menu extra to the menu bar? Or does your app just do it automatically without the user telling it to do so?

I think that's the distinction, your app must only add an extra when instructed to do so. Also if the primary purpose of your app is to create  a menu extra (eg, I have one that puts a calendar in the menu bar) then just launching the app is an implicit instruction, so it can be added automatically.

Ultimately, this rule really is vague and can't be clarified. What it comes down to, is that there should not be many menu extras in a user's menu bar unless the user explicitly chooses to have them. So unless your app *really* needs a menu extra, you must disable it by default.

If you think the reviewer should have allowed your app through then reply to the rejection explaining your position. I've had an app change to approved once after doing that.

If they still reject your app, then you can appeal the app rejection.

Alternatively, just disable the menu extra by default and have a button somewhere to add it to the menu bar.

Also, all of this assumes you are using NSStatusItem and not the "real" menu extra system — which is a private API. Only NSStatusItem menu extras can be placed in the app store as far as I know.